# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scikits.talkbox'

Tags: python

i am importing

```
from scikits.talkbox.features import mfcc
from scipy.io import wavfile
```

but getting this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scikits.talkbox'

i tried `pip install scikits.talkbox` but it is not working

Comment: The usual suspect for this error is that you have multiple Python installations.  Are you running your commands in an IDE, like PyCharm or Jupyter or VSCode?

Comment: Are you using a virtual enviroment? If not, set one up and try to install it with pip again.